# Unity - 2D - Draw a sprite with it's "real" size

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, rendering, sprite

Is there a way to draw a 10x20px sprite always with 10x20px regardless of the resolution?
I don't mean to add it as a UI/canvas object, I want to be able to place it in the world and move it or move the camera.
thx for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using an [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Image.html) component you can hit the <kbd>Set Native Size</kbd> button in the Inspector

> Set the dimensions of the image box to the original pixel
>   size of the Texture.

In order to move it and place it in 3D it has to be a child of a [`Canvas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html) with `RenderMode = WorldSpace`

Then also note the options of the `Canvas` especially the `CanvasScaler` -> `Reference Pixels Per Unit` value. It should be `1` in your case before hitting <kbd>Set Native Size</kbd> in the `Image`.

Comment: But how can I move it like it were a child of one of my moving gameobjects? Isn't there anything I could do with the sprite renderer ot the settings of my sprite?

Comment: what about making the `Canvas` a child of your moving objects then?

Comment: Ok you have a point, forgot that I can do this :)
But how do I have to configure the canvas to work with any resolution including 4:3 or 2:1 to ensure that the image isn't too much left / right?

Comment: I would simply give the `Canvas` any size (doesn't matter) and set the Image to its center using the absolute (not stretched)  positioning and `0,0,0`.

Comment: Well then I'll make it realy small ^^
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting the Camera ortographic size to the correct size. Try the 2D Pixel Perfect Camera package by Unity https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/13/2d-pixel-perfect-how-to-set-up-your-unity-project-for-retro-8-bits-games/

The script in that package will automatically set your Camera ortographic size with provided parameters. If you want to manually set it, the formula is:

> Camera ortographic size = vertical resolution / PPU / 2

Vertical resolution means the target vertical resolution that your sprite was designed for. For example, if your sprite is designed to look pixel perfect on 1600x900 screen, then the vertical resolution will be 900.

PPU means the pixel per unit, by default all imported sprites are set to 100.

Comment: I don't want to adjust my camra I only need a few sprites at my minimap on a guaranteed size (but even on the minimap not all should be like this).